# SocialAuth - Facebook Authentication - Specify which access rights are requested

Tags: java, facebook, authentication, oauth, socialauth

I want to realize a simple login via facebook on my website. I used SocialAuth for that and it is working pretty fine. But if i login via facebook, the facebook app needs the confirmation for a lot of access rights like, posting to the wall and so on.

I don't need this rights. Can i somehow define, which rights are requested (basically i need none - just the login). This is my code:

```
//Create an instance of SocialAuthConfgi object
   SocialAuthConfig config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault();

  //load configuration. By default load the configuration from oauth_consumer.properties. 
  //You can also pass input stream, properties object or properties file name.
   config.load();

  //Create an instance of SocialAuthManager and set config
  SocialAuthManager manager = new SocialAuthManager();
  manager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);

  //URL of YOUR application which will be called after authentication
  String successUrl = "http://opensource.brickred.com/socialauthdemo/socialAuthSuccessAction.do";

  // get Provider URL to which you should redirect for authentication.
  // id can have values "facebook", "twitter", "yahoo" etc. or the OpenID URL
  String url = manager.getAuthenticationUrl(id, successUrl);

  // Store in session
  session.setAttribute("authManager", manager);
```

My config looks something like this. Can i define this here in some way?

```
#facebook
graph.facebook.com.consumer_key =   152190004803645
graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret = 64c94bd02180b0ade85889b44b2ba7c4
graph.facebook.com.secure = true
graph.facebook.com.request_token_url = /oauth/access_token
graph.facebook.com.authorization_url = /oauth/authorize
graph.facebook.com.access_token_url = /me
graph.facebook.com.signature_method = HMAC-SHA1
graph.facebook.com.transport_name = GET
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom permission like this.

```
graph.facebook.com.consumer_key =   152190004803645
graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret = 64c94bd02180b0ade85889b44b2ba7c4
graph.facebook.com.custom_permission = email,user_birthday,user_location
```

No need to set other properties. But if you want to set other properties, then only you can set request_token_url (for OAuth1.0), authentication_url and access_token_url. This feature is available from socialauth-4.2

```
graph.facebook.com.authentication_url
graph.facebook.com.access_token_url
```

Comment: Is there a documentation on these config parameters? I did not find any on the socialauth site: https://code.google.com/p/socialauth

Comment: There are lot of comments in sample properties file. Comments shows clearly what configuration you can do. Go through the following link, specially read comments. http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/SampleProperties OR you can go through https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth/wiki/Sample-Properties

Comment: In addition to your answer, you need to set Permissions to Permission.CUSTOM in AuthManager